# sql query in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver

I am trying to fetch rows from the database which has data1 field euqal to values from a string array. this is how i am trying to do.. but it is giving a sqliteexception.

```
String[] Projection = { ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, ContactsContract.Data.DATA6, ContactsContract.Data.DATA8 };
String Selection = ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "= ? ";
c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, Projection, Selection, id, null);
```

c is the cursor. and id is the string array which contains strings which should match with those in the DATA1 field of the database.
is there any other way of doing this?? perhaps using 'IN' ?
the logcat exception is :

07-03 17:42:49.118   391   391 E DatabaseUtils: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x584c30

Comment: You should never have to use `IN`. Also, next tie you should post your logcat with the information about the `SQLiteException`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `id` contains only one String.

And make sure you call `c.moveToFirst()` before you attempt to extract values from the `Cursor`, as it may be empty.

Comment: but id is already defined as a String array containing say 5 elements. I dont really get what your statement means.

Comment: 5 elements?? Why do you need 5 elements? There is only one `?`, so there should be only one `String` in the array to replace the `?`.

Comment: i already have the String[] id with say 5 elements. I dont understand how to write the query.ok. i understand my query is wrong.

yea, i am already doing  the c.moveToFirst();

Comment: OK, I will tell you one more time lol. `id` should not have 5 elements, it should have 1 element. no more, no less.

Comment: more precisely, the `selectionArgs[]` should have the same number of elements as the number of `?` in the `selection` string

Comment: I guess you dont get my exact problem. I have this string array already. I have to write a query so as to fetch the rows from the database which contains the elements of the array as values in DATA1 field. I cant do anything with the String array id. it is passed to me as an argument.

Comment: Can you post all of your code including the content of the `String[]` id argument, etc.? Maybe call `Log.v()` on your `projection`, `selection`, and `selectionArgs[]` before you perform the query? That is how I would debug the issue. Other than that, it seems like the problem is something else that you are not telling us.